# Using Github over HTTP (not https)

Tags: git, http, github, bitbucket

I'm working on a class project and want to use `git` for working with my team. However, our high school blocks all external traffic that's not on port 80, which puts `SSH` and, notably, `HTTPS`, out of the picture. I have prior permission to use a `git` repo, and I've sent emails to the proper people for getting this kind of thing to work, but policies don't allow for it.

How can I access these over HTTP?

If not possible, does anyone know of any free git services that support  plain old HTTP? I've tried `github` and `bitbucket` and know that neither of them do (they support `HTTPS` instead).

Comment: Hey, did my answer actually work for you?

Comment: Partially, I also needed to set GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY environment variable to true, but I thought that wouldn't be very relevant to the original question, since it had to do with a seperate issue.

Comment: that sucks. I wonder if you could find an HTTPS proxy running on port 80 to fool the firewall. But they could probably block that too by requiring the traffic to be plain HTTP, in which case we'll need even more clever tricks.

Comment: I'm fairly certain the district doesn't do packet inspection on most traffic and plenty of non-http traffic can get through on port 80. Proxies, on the other hand, are aggressively blocked individually by IP address